# getElementById doesn't get textarea content

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

This might seem simple for someone that knows: This script gets a `DIV` tag when the button is clicked, and opens a new page with the contents. But I want it to show the contents of the `textarea` after the user has typed something in.

Any ideas? code is:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  var win=null;
  function printIt(printThis)
  {
    win = window.open();
    self.focus();
    win.document.open();
    win.document.write('<'+'html'+'><'+'head'+'><'+'style'+'>');
    win.document.write('body, td { font-family: Verdana; font-size: 10pt;}');
    win.document.write('<'+'/'+'style'+'><'+'/'+'head'+'><'+'body'+'>');
    win.document.write(printThis.innerHTML);
    win.document.write('<'+'/'+'body'+'><'+'/'+'html'+'>');
    win.document.close();
    win.print();
  }
</script>
</head><body>
    
  <div id="activity5">
    <blockquote>
      <table border="0" cellpadding="3">
      </table>
      <form id="form4" name="form1" method="post" action="">
      <textarea name="Activity1a4" cols="80" rows="15" class="s23" id="ta1"></textarea>
      <p>
        <input name="print4" type="submit" id="print4" value="Print" onclick="printIt(document.getElementById('activity5')); return false"/>
          * Retain this learning activity as part of your portfolio of evidence.</p>
      <p>Check your findings with the correct answer in the back of this Learner Resource under 'Learning activity answers'.</p>
      </form>
    </blockquote>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

You get the contents of a textarea with `.value`, not with `.innerHTML`.

That means that getting `activity5` innerHTML will NOT include the text that has been typed in the child textarea.  If you want to include that text, you will have to separately retrieve that text with `.value` on the textarea and insert it into the new text area in the new page.

Comment: It's not a `textarea`, it's a `div`.

Comment: @Guffa - I added more to my answer.  The basic issue is that the text the user types in a textarea is NOT included in the innerHTML of the parent object.  They will have to manually fetch that text and insert it where they want it.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to get the contents of the textarea separately with the `value` attribute, then set it explicitly the same way. Take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/EPvWV/ for an example of how to do that.